How can an expansion valve decrease temperature
Let's consider a refrigerant system, a vapor-compression refrigeration. The ambient temperature is say $\vartheta_A=35^{\circ}C$ and I want to have a freezer that cools down to $\vartheta_B=-20^{\circ}C.$
The working fluid that is at some $\vartheta_{A'}>\vartheta_A=35^{\circ}C$ (heat flows from higher to lower temperature) condenses in the condenser (it is giving off heat to the environment) and is now still at $\vartheta_{A'}$ (phase change is an isothermal process) after the condensation.
We now have to decrease its temperature to less than $-20^{\circ}C$, so some $\vartheta_{B'}<\vartheta_B=-20^{\circ}C$ in order for the working fluid to be able to evaporate using the heat obtained from the system at $\vartheta_B=-20^{\circ}C.$
I read about the expansion valve, but it just seems like a system that uses a membrane and a pin to regulate the flow of the working fluid in order to regulate the output temperature when it leaves the evaporator.
For the lowering the temperature part, it only has one little opening that is meant to lower the temperature.
My question is, how can it decrease the temperature for more than $55^{\circ}C$ when using only that little opening as the only way of decreasing it? Is the isentropic expansion so powerful in order to cool it down for that much?
How come than when I have a water spray bottle, it doesn't cool down that much?

Do a search for the phenomenon of "free expansion" - think of aerosol cans. A time I saw it happen was when I was using a big welder on full power continuously, suddenly started to mess around and the gas valve was covered in a ball of frost. Had to wait for it to warm up.

Hi. Thanks for the reply. I know about adiabatic expansion, but it is usually regarded as a process for gasses. Our working fluid is a combination of fluid-vapor when it is being expanded, so I don't really get how can it cool by that much (because fluid can not expand as much as gases can).

So your vapor is not a gas?

this statement may be an indication of a misunderstanding  ... We now have to decrease its temperature to less than −20∘C

as long as the compressor is powerful enough to raise the temperature of the working fluid above 35∘C then heat can continue to be extracted from the system to the surrounding space

I partially answered this question in my answer to your air conditioning question. If you need more information let me know and I'll go into more detail. (If you sprayed your water bottle into a partial vacuum (low pressure) it would cool down much more.)

you learned about volume versus temperature, right?

Have you ever seen a CO2 fire extinguisher in use? Inside the tank is liquid CO2 at high pressure and ambient temperature. When released the liquid evaporates and instantly cools so that it produces a cold gas and CO2 "snowflakes". CO2 freezes at -109.2 F! That's a drop in temperature of over 180F.

@TigerGuy Saturated vapor does not obey the Gas Laws.

@SolarMike Vapor is a gas, yes. But we have a mixture (of I don't know exactly what % of gas) and your explanation was only with gasses. How does the liquid part come into play? Can you cool liquids when they go through an expansion valve? By how much?

@jsotola If the temperature of the room which we want to cool is $35^{\circ}C$ and the temperature of the working fluid is also $35^{\circ}C$ than heat exchange would last infinitely long. Look up the second law of thermodynamics. There has to be a temp. difference.

It’s to do with the vapor pressure of the liquid. When water is at 100C its vapor pressure is one atmosphere - that’s why it boils.
On top of Mt Everest, where the air pressure is about 1/3 of an atmosphere, water boils at about 70C. There is no way you can get liquid water hotter than that. Forget about a nice cuppa!
In a refrigeration system the compressor maintains a low pressure in the evaporator so that the refrigerant boils at a low temperature. It cannot remain liquid. As it evaporates it cools due to its latent heat.
The expansion valve has just a little (variable size) hole in it, so that it controls the amount of refrigerant passing through. It only allow sufficient refrigerant to pass to maintain the pressure in the evaporator. Too much, and the evaporator is flooded and will not cool efficiently (plus you have the danger of liquid refrigerant slugging back into the compressor and damaging it.) Too little and there is insufficient cooling. The opening of the expansion valve is controlled by the pressure in the evaporator. As the pressure drops, the valve opens more.
As the refrigerant passes through the expansion valve into the low pressure region some of it will flash off instantly into vapor and bring the temperature of the remainder down to the coil temperature. The coil temperature is determined solely by the pressure in the coil. There is a one to one relationship between temperature and pressure for a liquid in equilibrium with its vapor, which is determined by the vapor pressure of the refrigerant at that temperature.
When you boil water it's temperature is 100C and its vapor pressure is 1 bar. No matter how much heat you put in, the temperature and pressure remains the same. All the applied heat goes into the latent heat of water - it does not go into expanding the water vapor. Exactly the same thing happens in an evaporator; you are boiling the refrigerant. The temperature remains the same and the pressure remains the same. All the heat goes into the latent heat of the refrigerant. This is very basic theory. No heat goes into expanding the refrigerant vapor!
The pressure is only dependent on the vapor pressure of the refrigerant at that temperature. I'll say it one more time; when you maintain the pressure above a refrigerant liquid at some constant value the temperature of that refrigerant is set absolutely. It doesn't matter what temperature the liquid was before it entered the low pressure region.
One proviso, this is only really true for liquid and vapor in equilibrium, and the is not the case in an evaporator coil. That said, all calculations and design criteria are based on that fact.
Here's an image from researchgate.net showing a pressure/enthalpy diagram for R134a. The path of the refrigerant during the refrigeration cycle is shown. You can see that heat is absorbed in the evaporator and discharged in the condenser at constant pressure. The temperature also remains constant here.

This diagram shows the state of the refrigerant (from hvac-eng.com)

I am interested in the process of temperature decrease. The last paragraph kind of touches on that point, but it is not very well explained. Your answer to my other question is the one that would pass better here.
